# Change TextBox Text property inside Form constructor wont affect the binded setting

Tags: c#, binding, properties

Why when I change the TextBox Text property inside Form constructor it wont affect the binded setting?

Sample:
A TextBox inside a Form. The Text property is binded to a Settings string.
If the TextBox.Text is changed inside the Form constructor, the binded Setting wont change its value. Although, outside the construct, it does change (as expected, since they are binded).

I don't know how the binding "magic" works, and maybe I'm missing something here. But this behavior is at least odd.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ChangeText();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeText();
        }

        private void ChangeText()
        {
            //Settings.Default.TextBox1Text == "Original settings value"
            textBox1.Text = "Changed";

            //Call to this method inside Constructor:
            // Settings.Default.TextBox1Text still equals its original value
            //Settings.Default.TextBox1Text == "Original settings value"

            //Call to this method outside Constructor:
            // Settings.Default.TextBox1Text == "Changed"
        }
    }
}

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", global::WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default, "TextBox1Text", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 41);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.textBox1.Text = global::WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.TextBox1Text;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(157, 41);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
```

Comment: "x still equals its original value" - what original value do you mean? It has none, because it didn't exist before.

Comment: I meant Settings.Default.TextBox1Text.

Comment: I edited the code, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: it's uncommon. Are you sure you're not messing around with `Settings.Default.TextBox1Text` somewhere else in the code? Maybe in the rest of your `ChangeText` method?

Comment: No, just copy my code and see by yourself. You will need to create the setting entry and rebind it.